# Suppress warning for fopen

Tags: c++, fopen

Is there a way to suppress the warning for fopen (VS 2012 is suggesting I use fopen_s)? The following commands don't seem to work

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Comment: Are you putting those defines *before* you include `stdio.h`?

Answer (score 0):

Add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to your Project Properties under Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions.